# ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "*.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Exact error: `ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "dashboard.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.):`

Now, this is odd because this app is a clone of an app i already have deployed to heroku, and that app works with the EXACT same code and files.  I do remember having similar issues, albiet this was months ago so the exact remedy i did i cannot remember.  Although, i do believe all i had to do was precompile the assets locally and then it worked.

I have tried:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
-yarn install
-success Nothing to install.
-success Save lockfile
-writing / / /
```

..

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

-same as above

I know for a fact i did not try or do the following because i read it's not the right way to go about with production.  But in desperation i tried:

```
config.assets.compile = true #from false
```

This doesn't allow the app to start and breaks it.  No errors aside from connection `closed without response`.

I have restarted the app after each attempt as well.

When i run:

```
rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 13.0.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 12.3.3. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
..../config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
..../config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
..../config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
..../Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
..../Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
..../config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
..../config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
..../config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
..../Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
..../Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is going on here and what can be done to solve it?

The app is EXACTLY the same aside from a new DB, new git remote, new master key, etc.

Comment: I've always had to clobber first if I'm precompiling. There's also this where you define paths to precompile in the config https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: @MikeHeft in my original app, i never had to do that (ie, defining the stylesheets in assets.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this and no other posts are helping..

Here are the steps after cloning and app, and adding new git remote to use for heroku...

1. add stylesheets to assets.rb
2. precompile locally
3. push to heroku

I kept pushing to heroku just after adding it to the assets.rb which i could not understand why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Ya, I had to clobber locally when I was in school. But at my job, I use the precompile in the assets.rb and can continually push to heroku without issue. Also, I use the Heroku Procfile to be able to run `heroku local` that runs the rails server in a simulated heroku environment, which will throw asset errors if not defined in `assets.rb`

Comment: That's cool.  Never knew you could simulate heroku like that. thanks